# How to avoid already-authorized page in Android facebook SDK 4.0.1

Tags: java, android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I just create a new application that log into Facebook with the newest Android SDK (v4.0.1), and I always get a page with

> You already authorized App.

Here my OnCreate in the MainActivity in my app:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null ||
            Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null) {
        // User should be logged, but process never go in this condition
    }
    perm.add("email");
    perm.add("user_friends");
    perm.add("user_likes");
    perm.add("public_profile");
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mLoginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    mLoginManager.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, this);
    mLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, perm);
```

How can I check if this user had already logged/authorized this application ?

SOLVED: This page only appears in emulator, not on devices.